# How to validate Browser Error's message with cypress

Tags: cypress

For example if user dont fill this field and press "continue" button, this error message will pop up.
I wonder is there a way with Cypress that I check that error message was displayed?

Kind regards

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can make this assert : `cy.get('input:invalid').should('have.length', 1)`
See https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-documentation/pull/1919/files how to assert the validation message

Comment: Thank you for you answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an older question but here is another solution.

```
 cy.get(`[data-testid="XXXX"]`)
      .invoke('prop', 'validationMessage')
      .should((text: string) => {
        expect(text).to.contain(YYYY);
   });
```

Using the above code here is what happens:

1. You grab the input / textarea element using cy.get *Note*: it is recommended to use a data-testid or obtain the element by something less brittle so the test doesn't fail if the text changes etc.
2. Using the invoke method, you can check validationMessage against prop then then, obtain the inner text and use expect to check if it's valid. This is very handy if you use custom validation messages.